# Как в stl контейнерах (например std::list) получить и удалить элемент из контейнера за один вызов функции?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Есть ли какая-то возможность забрать элемент из std::list одновременно удаляя его (не вызывая отдельно два метода front и pop_front)?  Если такого метода или возможности нет, то какова мотивация комитета не добавлять такой метод в стандарт?

```
// Например сделать так. 
auto val = list.take_front();
// Заместо 
auto val = list.front();
list.pop_front();
```

Comment: в примере заместо тоже будет копирование

Comment: @ARHovsepyan убрал коментарий про копирование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что все стандартные контейнеры спроектированы предоставлять хранилище для хранимых в них объектов. Поддержка возможности забрать какой либо элемент из контейнера потребовала бы необходимости реализовывать поддержку дробления и отчуждения внутреннего хранилища контейнеров, что является делом не тривиальным.

Поддержку же копирования или перемещения существующего элемента можно сделать тривально, например

```
 value_type take_front()
 {
     auto val{::std::move(front())};
     pop_front();
     return val;
 }
```

Но, как видите, большой экономии тут бы не вышло.

Возможность добавления и забирания элементов реализуется в интрузивных контейнерах, которые спроектированы не предоставлять хранилище для хранимых в них объектов, а делигировать это пользователю. В этом примере создается только один экземпляр объект `t_Item` который добавляется, а затем изымается из контейнера не создавая дополнительных экземпляров:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

#include <cstdlib>

class tag_ItemListBaseHook;

using t_ItemListBaseHook = ::boost::intrusive::list_base_hook
<
    ::boost::intrusive::tag<tag_ItemListBaseHook>
,   ::boost::intrusive::link_mode<::boost::intrusive::safe_link>
>;

class t_Item final: public t_ItemListBaseHook
{
    private: int m_value{22};
};

using t_Items = ::boost::intrusive::list
<
    t_Item
,   ::boost::intrusive::base_hook<t_ItemListBaseHook>
,   ::boost::intrusive::constant_time_size<false>
>;

int main()
{
    t_Item item{};
    t_Items items{};
    items.push_back(item);
    items.pop_back();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как можно увидеть в [описании этого класса](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/), такого метода нет. Хотя во многих языках программирования `pop` как раз удаляет и сразу возвращает значение (так, например, в JavaScript'e).

Это сделано с целью предотвратить проблемы с памятью. Что, если в списке не число, а объекты кастомного класса? Возвращать ссылку на него? А он может быть уже удалён с вызовом деструктора. Накладывать ограничение на класс, чтобы у него был определён конструктор копирования? Тоже не вариант. Куда проще конечному юзеру класса (т.е, разработчику, Вам) подписать одну строку решения для своей конкретной ситуации.

На enSO несколько лет назад был [такой же вопрос про **std::queue**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25035691/5308802), там Вы можете найти ещё больше пояснений.

Comment: а также, нужно избежать разбуханию кода(с таким успехом можно написать сотни методов.) . Класс должен иметь только необходимые инструменты

Comment: @AivanF очевидно что делать перемещение объекта (это одновременно самый быстрый и безопасный способ). А если rval-конструктора нет то выключать этот метод у контейнера через enable_if.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ну этого метода мне постоянно не хватает. Я думаю это очень частый кейс, переместить объект из контейнера в пользовательскую область.

Comment: Зря вы javascript вспомнили. В нем нет ни списков, ни вообще какой-либо возможности для контейнера размещать какие либо объекты внутри себя.

Comment: @mrFieldy, так  напишите свой производный класс(можно шаблонный, чтобы базовым классом был любой контейнер), определите этот метод и пользуйтесь.   Может быть для вас и частый кейс, но в общем наврятли

Comment: "Это сделано с целью предотвратить проблемы с памятью. " О каких проблемах с памятью идет речь? Такие методы могут возвращать объект по значению. Где вы тут видите проблемы с памятью? Требование поддержки копирования (в исходном варианте требований) для стандартных контейнеров и так есть.